# how to give flag option in stanford-nlp program?

Tags: stanford-nlp

The site suggest that i can use several flags 
https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html

But how to use it, I tried doing it this way

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.NaturalLogicAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * A demo illustrating how to call the OpenIE system programmatically.
*/
public class OpenIEDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
// Create the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie");
props.setProperty("openieformat","ollie");
props.setProperty("openieresolve_coref","1");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// Annotate an example document.
Annotation doc = new Annotation("Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president.");
pipeline.annotate(doc);

// Loop over sentences in the document
for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
  // Get the OpenIE triples for the sentence
  Collection<RelationTriple> triples = sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);
  // Print the triples
  for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {
    System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
        triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
        triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
        triple.objectLemmaGloss());
  }
}
 }
}
```

I have added

```
props.setProperty("openieformat","ollie");
props.setProperty("openieresolve_coref","1");
```

But its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For StanfordCoreNLP, flags/properties for individual annotators are set with an `annotator.flag` name. And boolean flags have value "false" or "true". So, what you have is close to right, but needs to be:

`props.setProperty("openie.format","ollie");
props.setProperty("openie.resolve_coref","true");`

Comment: One thing I discovered afterwards, I  think will have to add another annotator dcoref, for complete working